# in-place Update Leaflet GeoJSON feature

Tags: leaflet

I was hoping that GeoJSON.addData() would return the newly created subLayer of the GeoJSON object, but it does not. Why Do I need something like this?

(currently using Leaflet 1.0Beta2)

I am using Leaflet GeoJson to show live data in a GeoJSON (point, line, polygon). It is a CRUD interface (Create, Update and Delete). I receive WebSocket messages with GeoJSON data, each one with a GUID.

I the case of a **CREATE** I just do a GeoJSon.AddData() to the appropriate layer.

But for the **UPDATE** and **DELETE** I want a handle for the layer that was added to the GeoJSON so that I can update its location, or update the Geometry. addData is not giving me this handle. And it is really hard to get it from onEachFeature() or from pointToLayer()

Currently, I do have a way that works but ugly. I have to do is search the entire layer with GeoJSon.eachLayer(fn)
whenever an update or delete occurs. It seems a bit expensive.

{even if Leaflet is not truly engineered for this live r/t display of data, it is working, and it seems sad if you cannot use it for watching a lot of sensor data, IoT) as we are doing.

```js
this.delete = function (layerName, feature) {
    if (!(layerName in self.myLayers)) {
        alert("live.display: Missing Layer: " + layerName);
        return;
    }
    var layerInfo = Live.myLayers[layerName];
    var base = layerInfo.layer;
    var id = feature.properties.objectID;
    this.find(layerName, id, function (layer) {
        this.removeLayer(layer);
        Tools.debug(16, "live.delete:", "killed object: " + id);
    });
}
this.find = function (layerName, id, action) {
    var base = Live.myLayers[layerName].layer;
    base.eachLayer(function (feature) {
        if (!("objectID" in feature.feature.properties)) { return; }
        var objectID = feature.feature.properties.objectID;
        if (objectID == id) {
            action.call(base, feature);
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Instead (or in parallel) of "merging" all created GeoJSON features into a single Leaflet GeoJSON layer group (which you do with `addData`), why not creating first each feature in its own Leaflet GeoJSON layer, so that it gives you the handle you are looking for (then you could simply record this handle in an object / mapping with the key being your `objectID` for example)?

If desired, you could even still merge the individual layers into your single GeoJSON layer group after that.

```js
var myGeoJsonLayerGroup = L.geoJson().addTo(map);
var myFeaturesMap = {};

function addNewFeatureToGeoJsonLayerGroup(newGeoJsonData) {
  var newGeoJSONfeature = L.geoJson(newGeoJsonData);
  myFeaturesMap[newGeoJsonData.properties.objectID] = newGeoJSONfeature;
  myGeoJsonLayerGroup.addLayer(newGeoJSONfeature);
}

function updateFeature(updatedGeoJsonData) {
  var updatedFeature = myFeaturesMap[updatedGeoJsonData.properties.objectID];
  updatedFeature.clearLayers(); // Remove the previously created layer.
  updatedFeature.addData(updatedGeoJsonData); // Replace it by the new data.
}

function deleteFeature(deletedGeoJsonData) {
  var deletedFeature = myFeaturesMap[deletedGeoJsonData.properties.objectID];
  myGeoJsonLayerGroup.removeLayer(deletedFeature);
}
```

Demo (not using GeoJSON): http://jsfiddle.net/ve2huzxw/94/

---

**EDIT:**

A slightly more simple solution would be to store the reference to each individual layer through the `onEachFeature` function of the GeoJSON layer group:

```js
var myFeaturesMap = {};

var myGeoJsonLayerGroup = L.geoJson({
    onEachFeature: function (feature, layer) {
        myFeaturesMap[feature.properties.objectID] = layer;
    }
}).addTo(map);

function addNewFeatureToGeoJsonLayerGroup(newGeoJsonData) {
    myGeoJsonLayerGroup.addData(newGeoJsonData);
}

function updateFeature(updatedGeoJsonData) {
    deleteFeature(updatedGeoJsonData); // Remove the previously created layer.
    addNewFeatureToGeoJsonLayerGroup(updatedGeoJsonData); // Replace it by the new data.
}

function deleteFeature(deletedGeoJsonData) {
    var deletedFeature = myFeaturesMap[deletedGeoJsonData.properties.objectID];
    myGeoJsonLayerGroup.removeLayer(deletedFeature);
}
```

Comment: Do you have any insights as to which solution offered above would be less   cpu-bound and scale to more items tracked in real-time? (While I am easily handling 20 objects/second now) I know my users and they will push this to the breaking point). (that is why I went with the addData in the first case, instead of a full sub-layer for each GeoJSON feature. But I like what you are saying.

Comment: I guess the top one would be in O(2n) while the bottom in O(n) in terms of memory and somehow of CPU operations. I also realize that the top solution and the `deleteFeature` function of bottom one assume that you operate on individual Feature's, never on FeatureCollection's.

Comment: I went with the bottom solution, and it is working like a charm.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to store references to the actual layers being created, you can access them from the `layeradd` event on your `L.GeoJSON` instance:

```
var geojson = new L.GeoJSON().on(
    'layeradd', function (e) {
        console.log(e.layer);
    }
).addTo(map);

// This addData call will fire the handler above twice
// because it adds two features.
geojson.addData({
    "type": "FeatureCollection",
    "features": [{
        "type": "Feature",
        "properties": {},
        "geometry": {
            "type": "Point",
            "coordinates": [90, 0]
        }
    }, {
        "type": "Feature",
        "properties": {},
        "geometry": {
            "type": "Point",
            "coordinates": [-90, 0]
        }
    }]
});
```

Comment: Thanks, that is a very interesting point, that I should have seen, but I did not grok fully.

Comment: @Dr.YSG grok? What?

Comment: @fulvio grok: To understand profoundly through intuition or empathy.

Answer (score 1):

If someone still looking for another short method to update `GeoJSON`, you can try something like this,

```js
//function to clear the previous geojson feature
function clearMap() {
    map.eachLayer(function(layer){
        if(layer.myTag && layer.myTag === 'previousLayer'){
            lmap.removeLayer(layer);
        }
    });
}

function geojsonUpdate(geojsonData){
 var geojsonLayer = L.geoJson(geojsonData, {
    onEachFeature: function (feature, layer) {
        layer.myTag = 'previousLayer'
      );
    },
  });
 geojsonLayer.addTo(lmap);
 lmap.fitBounds(geojsonLayer.getBounds());
}

//function call
clearMap();
geojsonUpdate(data);
```