# Get a list of feature in a Leaflet layerGroup

Tags: javascript, leaflet

Looking at this function:

```
function addNewFeatureToGeoJsonLayerGroup(newGeoJsonData) {
    var newGeoJSONfeature = L.geoJson(newGeoJsonData);
    myFeaturesMap[newGeoJsonData.properties.objectID] = newGeoJSONfeature;
    myGeoJsonLayerGroup.addLayer(newGeoJSONfeature);
}
```

Source: [in-place Update Leaflet GeoJSON feature](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34501524/in-place-update-leaflet-geojson-feature)

It looks to me that you have to:

1. Create a new layer
2. Modify the layer as suited
3. Add this layer into `layerGroup` (so for each feature you have one layer
   in `layerGroup`)

I can't see anything on the lines of `getFeatures()` for `layerGroup`. Do I need to loop through each layer for that?

UPDATE: [The `L.geoJson` API seems to be missing an API that would make it symmetric.](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet/issues/1416)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to get the list of child layers / features within a given Layer Group, then you would use [`layerGroup.getLayers()`](http://leafletjs.com/reference-1.0.3.html#layergroup-getlayers) (works also with a GeoJSON layer group).

The issue arises when you want to access a very specific child layer, without having a direct reference to it, but only some form of ID (typically a GeoJSON property). In this situation, Leaflet does not know which property you use as ID, so it cannot provide a method out-of-the-box. The simple workaround is to maintain a separate mapping / hash / dictionary of your ID's to the Leaflet corresponding layers, as done in the [source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34501524/in-place-update-leaflet-geojson-feature) you mention, and also in the [last post](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet/issues/1416#issuecomment-266272071) of the Leaflet issue you link to.

Note that it is very similar to how Layer Group works internally: it maintains a hash of child layers, assigning them an internal `_leaflet_id` property.

If you do not maintain such a hash, then indeed, I am afraid you would have to loop through each of your child layers, and scan for the property you use as ID until you find your match.

If you *really* want to get rid of that parallel hash, but avoid having to loop every time, we could imagine overriding how Leaflet uses [`_leaflet_id`](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet/blob/master/src/core/Util.js#L48-L57) and use your own ID instead. But you would have also to provide extra unique ID's for Leaflet internal layers…