# Leaflet - How to create a marker using data from a pop-up form

Tags: javascript, leaflet, gis

I'm starting out in javascript and tieing myself in knots trying to solve this one.

I'd like a form to appear when the user clicks the map. When they fill in the form I'd like to create a marker at that location with the popup content for that marker set to the values from the form. I also send the form data to a database once they are done adding forms.

The form works but I can't work out how to access the popup location data from the function which handles the form submit.

Here is my code:

```
function onMapClick(e) {
    popLocation = e.latlng;
    var popup = L.popup({
        closeButton: true})
        .setLatLng(e.latlng)
        .setContent(popupForm)
        .openOn(map);

     $("#popup-form").submit(function(e){
         e.preventDefault();
         console.log(e);
         var geojsonFeature = {
            "type": "Feature",
            "properties": {
                "type": $("input[name='goodBad']:checked").val(),
                "location":  L.DomUtil.get('location').value,
                "reason": L.DomUtil.get('reason').value,
                "improve": L.DomUtil.get('improve').value
            },
            "geometry": {
                "type": "Point",
                "coordinates": popLocation
            }
        };

        L.geoJson(geojsonFeature, {
            pointToLayer: function (feature, latlng) {
                marker = L.marker(geojsonFeature.geometry.coordinates, {
                    icon: L.AwesomeMarkers.icon({icon: 'info', prefix: 'fa', markerColor: markCol}),
                    riseOnHover: true,
                    draggable: true //define the content to be added to the marker
                }).bindPopup(popupForm);
                marker.on("popupopen", onPopupOpen);
                openOn(map);
                return marker;
            }
        }).addTo(map);
        map.closePopup();
     });
```

The form if you need it is here:

```
var popupForm = '<form id="popup-form" class="form-container"> \
                <h2>Add a point:</h2>\
                <strong> The air quality here is: </strong> <br> \
                <label for="type">Good</label> \
                <input type="radio" name="goodBad" value ="good" id="good"> \
                <label for="type">Bad </label> \
                <input type="radio" name="goodBad" value = "bad" id="bad"> \
                    <br><br></c> \
                <label for="location"><b>Location Name</b></label> \
                <input type="text" placeholder="eg. Redbridge flyover" id="location" > \
                <label for="reason"><b>Why are you adding this point? - be specific!</b></label> \
                <input type="text" placeholder="eg. There is a traffic jam every saturday 11am" id="reason" > \
                <label for="solution"><b>How would you improve air quality at this location? <br>(If you ran the city)</b></label> \
                <input type="text" placeholder="eg. I\'d close the road when when school starts and stops" id="improve"> \
                <button type="submit" id="btn-submit" class="btn">Save</button> \
                <input type="hidden" id= "hiddenField" name="id" value="" /> \
            </form>';
```

Very many thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would go about solving this issue with the following steps:

1) render all points/markers via a geoJSON, lets call it foobarJSON for now.

2) On click event, capture the coordinate of where the map was clicked.

3) Then append that coordinate to foobarJSON and update leaflet with the new version of foobarJSON

4) Update your database with the new coordinate

for step 3 something like this might work:

```
function updateFeature(updatedGeoJsonData) {
  var updatedFeature = myFeaturesMap[updatedGeoJsonData.properties.objectID];
  updatedFeature.clearLayers(); // Remove the previously created layer.
  updatedFeature.addData(updatedGeoJsonData); // Replace it by the new data.
}
```

ref: [in-place Update Leaflet GeoJSON feature](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34501524/in-place-update-leaflet-geojson-feature)

Hope that helps

Comment: thanks, how would you avoid the markerID race condition when several people edit the map and send the result to the database? Were you referring to http://jsfiddle.net/ve2huzxw/94/

Comment: A simple approach would be to let the DB manage the ID creation, but if you need a more robust solution then you could use a message bus middleware.